# DataBindingUtil вылетает "int cannot be dereferenced"

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-data-binding

Имеется класс User c с полем

```java
private int mAge;
...
public int getAge() {
    return mAge;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    mAge = age;
}
```

разметка с TextView

```java
<TextView
    android:text="@{@string/age_format(user.age)}"
```

и res/strings

```java
<resources>
    <string name="age_format">age: %d</string>
```

при компиляции вылетает `int cannot be dereferenced`в сгеннерированном классе binding:

```java
@Override
protected void executeBindings() {
    int userAge = 0;
    t.testbinding.User user = mUser;
    if ((dirtyFlags & 0x3L) != 0) {
            if (user != null) {
                // read user.name
                userName = user.getName();
                // read user.age
                userAge = user.getAge();
            }

            // read @android:string/age_format
            userAgeAndroidStringAgeFormatUserAge = userAge.getResources().getString(R.string.age_format, userAge);
```

естественно ошибку кидает последняя приведенная строка. Вообще не пойму, чего оно примитив прилепило к коду получения строки с ресурса.
Как победить такое поведение?

П.С. IDE Intellij 2017.2

Comment: Примитив здесь `userAge` - он объявлен в начале метода и , вероятно перекрывает одноимённое поле класса, соответственно у `int` не может быть вызван `getResources()`

Comment: `getResources()` вызывается только в контексте. Поэтому я в недоумении

Comment: Поле `userAge` в этом классе есть? Если да, то скорее всего у `TextView` задан `id` с этим же именем - измените его на другой.

Comment: `userAge` в классах не используется. Но в `TextView` как `id` используется. Заменил и все пошло. И нигде примечаний не встречал, что нельзя использовать идентификаторы равнозначные сложению имени вариаблов+именам полей соответствующего класса.
Спасибо